# DB2 - Count string characters, not length

Tags: db2

I have a column on DB2 which we store a text. I want to know if there is a way to count how many characters are in a string, but without using the `Length()` function, let me explain. We have a string with exactly 1,000 characters, as you can see here: [IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PQ56N.jpg)

The total lentgh is 1,064, while there are 1,000 total characters, this is due to the non-western characters (the chinese and korean ones). So the DB2 `Length()` function also returns 1,064 in the query: [IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zEad3.jpg)

Is there a way to make DB2 returns 1,000 in this query instead of 1,064? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `CHARACTER_LENGTH()`

Availability may depend on your DB2 platform and version..

Comment: Thanks! It worked using `CHARACTER_LENGTH(columnName,CODEUNITS32)` !

Answer (score 0):

This actually counted the number of characters in field not the length of field;

```
select character_length(trim(columnname))
```